# org-mode changing parent todo state based on subtask todo state

Tags: emacs, org-mode, todo

I'd like to change automatically the todo state of the parent heading based on the TODO state of the child heading. Is there any function/setting to get this done?

E.g.

```
* TODO project 1
** TODO subtask 1
** HOLD subtask 2
```

change to

```
* HOLD project 1
** TODO subtask 1
** HOLD subtask 2
```

Comment: Not quite what you want but check out [this section in the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html#TODO-dependencies) and the variable `org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks` in particular.

Comment: No it's not about blocking, it's about changing the status of a parent based on the children todo states

Answer (score 1):

[org-edna](http://www.nongnu.org/org-edna-el/) should allow you to achieve what you want.

untested - this might do it:

```
* TODO project 1   
  :PROPERTIES:   
  :TRIGGER: descendants todo!(HOLD)   
  :END:
** TODO subtask 1
** HOLD subtask 2
```

Comment: I didn't know about org-edna, thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, the example doesn't work, because a trigger is an action to take when a heading is set to done. I'll go through org-edna and see if there is another solution.